# How can I use JQuery on my page?

Tags: jquery, css

On the screenshot, you see on the bottom there is a list of prices. I want it hidden by default and when I click on the button 'Prices', I want it to slide down from underneath. Then if I press it again I want the list to slide up again. How can I do this? Sorry if I didn't explain much, any questions please ask. 
[image]

Comment: This is the downside of allowing people to post images - massive PNG files being resized by the browser. Sigh.

Comment: Does anyone else find the content of that image suspicious? What the hell does this service do?

Comment: Harvests the power of zombie networks to pad the stats of one's FB page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) and [slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) animation. The documentation has a nice example that you can copy from, but basically you want to put the part that slides up and down in a separate `div` with the css `display: none;` then add code like this:

```
$('#button').click(function () {
   if ($("#prices").is(":hidden")) {
      $("#prices").slideDown("slow");
   } else {
       $("#prices").slideUp("slow");
   }
});
```

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you. How can I have the page auto-scroll with the slide?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the JQuery UI (www.jqueryui.com) classes to perform SHOW/HIDE functionality on the price click event.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial:

http://net.tutsplus.com/javascript-ajax/build-a-top-panel-with-jquery/

Demo: http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/041_TopPanelWithJquery/demo/index.html

jQuery docs:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Basically what you want is:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#panel').slideToggle('slow');
});
```